# Wrong or incomplete object_id from Notifications table using FQL

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am working on displaying Notification in my Android App. The Notifications are fetched using an FQL query to the Notifications table and then displaying the result in a ListView. Now, to preserve a good user Experience I want the user to stay in the App when he clicks on a notification. And I have had partial success so far in doing this so far.

The Notification table has two important columns, namely, the `object_id` and the `object_type`. When the result to the query returns the object_type as *`stream`*, the `object_id` is correct and matches the `id` if a query to the "me/home" using the Graph API were to be made. This is essential because I have a Newsfeed activity and a NewsfeedDetails activity which shows the clicked posts details such as the number of comments, likes and the actual comments in a list with the post content in its header.

However, when the `object_type` returns *`photo`*, the `object_id`, if checked in the Graph API Explorer gives and 803 exception. The *id* is basically, just wrong! To overcome that hurdle, I extracted a partial *object_id* from the `*href*` column of the Notifications table. But this resulting `object_id`, when compared to the `id` from the Graph API call to "me/home" is always different. If the extracted `object_id` is checked in the Graph API Explorer, it shows the photo object as agaist the post object.

Is there a way in which I can get the *object_id* which matches the *id* from a call to "me/home"? And if none of this post makes sense, I will add relevant examples. I am against the wall trying to search for a possible solution to this and have already filed a bug on FB.

I really appreciate any help / advice you Gurus on SO can afford me. Thanks.